# Binding objects to radio buttons c#

Tags: c#, oop, object

I new to OOP so I don't know if what I'm asking if possible, but here goes. I have two radio buttons "radiobutton1" and "radiobutton2" on my form. I have a Vehicle class with an instance called "car1". I also have a Motor class with two instances called "smallMotor" and "largeMotor". I'm trying to make a method called "SetMotor" that is supposed to set either the smallMotor or largeMotor as the motor for car1. This method is supposed to take two boolean values, represented by the two radio buttons to determine which motor object to set for car1. I tried the following, but it doesn't work and gave me errors. Here's my code:

The main form:

```html
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication12
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Motor largeMotor;
        Motor smallMotor;
        Vehicle car1;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            largeMotor = new Motor(2000);
            smallMotor = new Motor(1000);
            car1 = new Vehicle();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            car1.SetModel(textBoxModel.Text);
            car1.SetNumDoors((int)numericUpDown1.Value);
            car1.SetMotor(radioButton1.Checked, radioButton2.Checked); 
        }
    }
}
```

My motor class:

```html
    class Motor
    {
        private int power;

        public Motor(int p)
        {
            power = p;
        }
    }
```

The Vehicle class:

```
class Vehicle
{
    private Motor motor;

    public void SetMotor(bool smallMotor, bool largeMotor)
    {
        if (largeMotor)
        {
            motor = largeMotor;
        }
        else
            motor = smallMotor;
    }
}
```

The error this gives me  is:

> Error  6   Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool' to 'WindowsFormsApplication12.Motor'.

So, is it possible to bind the two motor objects to the radio buttons? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: what is your `motor` object ?, there must be motor.IsLarge or something like it

Comment: `largeMotor` is a boolean whereas `motor` is an object of Class Motor thats why you are getting `Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool' to 'WindowsFormsApplication12.Motor'`.

Comment: You should know that there is a additional bracket in your source code

Comment: Can you please add more of your source code because the main bug that I see at the moment is that your motor field(guess its a field inside your form) and you say my Motor instance is equals to boolean value which makes no sense. What @ShaminderSAujla said is quite good. You could refactor your Vehicule class to have a single property called IsLarge. And there's no need for two radio buttons. A single radio button will do the trick. When not selected, IsLarge would be false  (small motor) and when selected, isLarge would be true (big motor).  And voila, no need for 2 radio buttons

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your current code, you are trying to assign `bool` value to a `Motor` which cannot be done as your code is strongly typed.

There is no distinction between your `largeMotor` and `smallMotor` object. If you need to know it later whether the motor is large or small, your `Vehicle` object will not be able to tell you that. Here is a quick recommendation as far as your class structure is concerned:

```
class Vehicle
{
    public Motor Motor
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

class Motor
{
    public MotorType Type
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

enum MotorType
{
    Large,
    Small
}

class SomeClass
{
    public void SetMotorType(bool isSmall)
    {
        // This object would probably come from some place else
        Vehicle vehicle = new Vehicle();
        vehicle.Motor = new Motor { Type = (isSmall) ? MotorType.Small : MotorType.Large };
    }
}
```

Now, `Vehicle.Motor.MotorType` will let you know all the time whether the motor is large or small.

Edit:

Forget programming and OOP for a while and think real World. There is a car it has engine and tyres. A class, in programming, is a representation of a complete real World object (only for now). Now, going by this understanding, there should be a class `Car` in your code. Now, car has Engine and Tyres. Engine and Tyre on their own are complete too. So you will need a class for `Engine` and `Tyre`. Next, you know car has engine and tyre. To relate these three classes in code, you can make use of properties like this:

```
class Car
{
public Engine Engine{get;set;}

// Since car has more than one tyres, it should be one to many relation
public List<Tyre> Tyres{get;set;}

}
```

Now, engine can then be broken down into parts like piston, cylinder etc. Based on how granular you want to go, piston could be a property of Engine or it could be a class too with properties like MadeOf, Diameter, Length etc. For sake of simplicity, I will not do deeper. So, how will you link these properties to Engine? By using properties. Hence,

```
class Engine{
// Or any other Piston attribute you are interested in.
public int PistonId{get;set;}

public decimal CylinderVolume{get;set;}
}
```

Similarly, Tyres to will be defined with the attributes they have. Like radius, whether they are tubeless or not and other properties. So,

```
class Tyre{
public int radius{get;set;}
public bool IsTubeless{get;set;}
}
```

Now, you can say Car has tubeless tyres so we can put `IsTubeless` property in the car. But think logically, it makes more sense for `Tyre` class object to know whether it is tubeless or not. This is how you can define your classes.

Earlier, I mentioned classes represent complete real World objects. Once you dig deep and stumble upon abstract classes, you will realize that this is not true. But leave that for later.

Comment: does not get simpler to use than this. Great answer !

Comment: Well written. Great answer indeed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. A lot of the stuff is new to me so I will try to make sense of it.

Comment: @grammer edited the response with some explanation. Hope that helps.